# Intersection number & non-singular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was looking at a proof of the following theorem...

Let $S/\mathbb{C}$ be a smooth projective surface, let $C$ be a non-singular irreducible curve on $S$. Then for all $L \in \text{Pic}\,S$, the intersection number $\langle \mathcal{O}_S(C), L \rangle$ is equal to $\text{deg}(L|_C)$.

Proof: we have an exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O}_S(-C) \to \mathcal{O}_S \to \mathcal{O}_C \to 0$ which remains exact upon tensoring with $L^{-1}$, hence giving an exact sequence $0 \to L^{-1}(-C) \to L^{-1} \to L^{-1} \otimes \mathcal{O}_C \to 0$. By additivity of the Euler-Poincaré characteristic, we get $\chi(\mathcal{O}_S) - \chi(\mathcal{O}_S(-C)) = \chi(\mathcal{O}_C)$ and $\chi(L^{-1}) - \chi(L^{-1}(-C)) = \chi(L|_C^{-1})$. This allows us to write the intersection number as $\langle \mathcal{O}_S(C) , L \rangle = \chi(\mathcal{O}_C) - \chi(L|_C^{-1}) = -\text{deg}(L|_C^{-1}) = \text{deg}(L|_C)$, by Riemann-Roch.

**Question**

Where did we use the fact that $C$ is non-singular? It has to be essential, but I don't see why...

References:

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/02-245/sclass5A.pdf

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/02-245/sclass6A.pdf

Comment: You apply Riemann-Roch for non-singular irreducible curves. There's a more  general Riemann-Roch for singular curves. I think you can find it in chapter 7 of Liu's book on alg. geometry.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't Corollary 3.18 on page 279 of Liu give exactly the formula I want, i.e. $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X(D)) = \deg D + \chi(\mathcal{O}_X)$, also without the assumption that $X$ is non-singular?

Comment: You mean thm 3.17, but that's surely a typo. I think you're right. Maybe the problem lies in the definition. Is the intersection number of $C$ with $L$ well-defined if $C$ is singular in Vakil's notes? Does he use the dvr associated to $C$?

Comment: Yes, I meant theorem 3.17, sorry. Vakil defines intersection numbers on page 3 of http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/02-245/sclass5A.pdf - as far as I can see he doesn't need non-singularity there, but I'm probably missing something? Thanks for helping...

Comment: The smoothness assumption is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement should work even when $C$ is not smooth, but the degree of $L|_C$ is not even defined for singular $C$ in Vakil's lecture notes. In fact, his notes only ever cover the smooth case - probably because it is more intuitive and he can save a lot of time by *not* generalizing. If you want to generalize, you will have to use Liu's definition 7.3.1 (p.275), and then the proof should just work in the same way.